# UIScrollView automatically scrolls to top on touch action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm using `UIScrollView` inside `UIViewController` using `AutoLayout`. I am setting content view height for `UIScrollView` like this

```
 if(IS_IPHONE_6) {
        self.contentViewHeight.constant = 750;
    }
    if(IS_IPHONE_5) {
        self.contentViewHeight.constant = 700;
    }
```

Everything works fine. It is scrolling correctly but when I scroll to bottom and then touch inside content view or I touch any subview of content view, It automatically scrolls up. It is happening in `iPhone 6` &  6P. It is working fine in `iPhone 5`. I went through many StackOverflow posts but couldn't get desired result. I tried to set

```
_scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
```

But It is not working. Please help me to stop automatic scrolling. I'm setting following constraints to `UIScrollview`.

[image]

Comment: have you pinned all 4 sides?

Comment: Yes, I pinned as shown in attachment.

Comment: Just remember you have to pin all 4 sides to your MAIN view, and also set the width of your scroll view to be equal of your main view. have you done these two?

Comment: Yes, I pinned all 4 sides and scroll view width is equal to width of content view. Is there anything else which I needs to add ?

Comment: I'm not setting top and bottom of UIScrollView to main view cause there is view on top and bottom of scroll view.

Comment: can you upload your project somewhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123619/discussion-between-do2-and-rains).

Comment: Sorry to say. I'm not the owner of this project. It is a project with more than 100 views and we are working in team. It is not allowed to expose the project.

Comment: obviously i didn't mean you upload the whole thing, just create a new project with one view replicating with the current set up that causes the issue(anything more lets talk in chat..)

Comment: I will upload to Github after making changes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I managed to stop automatic scrolling to top on touch up inside action. I disabled paging in storyboard and It worked for me. I've no idea why paging turn on automatic scrolling to top.

[image]